# angular 7.0 pwa service worker not loading css file

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

PWA works sometimes, other times does not load the css bundle, loads other files fine.  This is my first PWA attempt and not sure how to make the service worker load this file consistently.

Chrome Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I created the basic my-app with the following commands.

1. `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
2. `ng new my-app (selected no to router, used scss)`
3. `ng add @angular/pwa --project my-app`

   the only update i made to the code was to the styles.scss file adding:
   *body { background-color: yellow; }*
4. `ng build --prod`
5. moved files to IIS server (https)

Sometimes everything works connected and disconnected.  Other times I receive the below error:

[image] 
[image]

even though i see the css file in the cache
[image]